# Arabic Character Encoding Issue

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, configuration

In my web application, Some specific arabic character encoding to different arabic character in overall application. How to find the root cause to solve this issue?

Comment: What is the [Charset](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) of your application.  Have u checked [which](https://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets/character-sets.xhtml) one your app is using.  You want to make sure you use UTF-8 everywhere if possible

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Edit this Question to show the source code of both your Java/JSP and the rendered web page. Make as small and simple an example as possible.